# Issue calling an Action class from href (Struts 1.2)

Tags: action, href, struts-1

in /jsp/home.jsp

I have a tag  like this:

```
<a href="Load.do?id=someid">First</a>
```

In struts-config.xml there is:

```
<action path="/Load" scope="request" type="myPackage.Load">
    <forward name="Success" path="/jsp/home.jsp"/>  
</action>
```

When I execute my webapp and click on the link, the execute method of the Load class is never executed. I don't have exceptions.

In the web.xml file, I have:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't understand what could be the problem.

**EDIT**

The problem is with the menu3.js that I use to have a collapsible menu
(like the menu on the right [here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/401/Beginning-CSS-Web-Development))

Comment: What's the URL displayed in the address bar when you are in viewing /jsp/home.jsp? What's the URL displayed in the status bar when hovering with your mouse over the link?

Comment: @JB Nizet: 1) http://localhost:8080/myappdir/login.do 2) http://localhost:8080/myappdir/Load.do?id=4 for example

Comment: This looks right. Have you checked the logs? What happens when you click the link? Are you sure the method isn't executed?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Nothing happens. In the console there is no "Initialize action of type" correspondig to Load. Moreover, I have put some System.out.println in the execute method, but nothing.

Comment: You should at least have a 404 or something. What happens if you add a breakpoint in the action servlet and execute it line by line with your debugger?

Comment: @JB Nizet: the method execute isn't reached